# how can i get and store values in mysql from function argument in python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-workbench

```
def insert(title,author,year,isbn):
    con= mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="junai2104",database="book")
    cur=con.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO book(title,author,year,isbn)VALUES ('$title','$author',%d,%d)")
    con.commit()
    con.close()
insert('test2','test2',1234,13525545)
```

And i got a error message like this

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%d,%d)' at line 1

how can i insert values by using function

Comment: 1) How you pass value for the param  ..2 )  check for ISBN should be a string 3  what are the '$title','$author'  ? (seems php var )  ..

Comment: Mind the SQL injections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def insert(title, author, year, isbn):
    con = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="junai2104", database="book")
    cur = con.cursor()
    sql_statement = "INSERT INTO book(title,author,year,isbn) VALUES ( '{}' , '{}', {}, {} )".format(str(title), str(author), year, isbn)
    cur.execute(sql_statement)
    con.commit()
    con.close()
insert('test1','test2',1234,13525545)
```

Comment: how can i search a value form the database

Comment: @ArunjunaiRajan Please ask this as another question explaining what exactly you want to search.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this once:

```
def insert(title,author,year,isbn):
    con= mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="junai2104",database="book")
    cur=con.cursor()
    sql_statement='INSERT INTO book(title,author,year,isbn) VALUES ('
    sql_statement = sql_statement + "'" + title + "','" + author + "'," + year + "," + isbn + ")"
    cur.execute(sql_statement)
    con.commit()
    con.close()
insert('test2','test2',1234,13525545)
```

Comment: Mind the SQL injections.